# Is there string concatenation in OPL?

Tags: opl

I was wondering if there is a string concatenation syntax/function in the IBM/ILOG OPL language? I used `+` in my OPL model like:

```
{names[i] + "_" | i in I}
```

but got an error.

I am using CPLEX studio 12.6, and I went through the help and couldn't find any such function. Googling around show there is [append](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_append.html?lang=en) for int arrays, but not much for String. Any pointers how to do String concatenation in the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do do string concat you can use scripting.

```
range r=1..3;
string names[i in r]="item"; 

execute
{
for(var i in r) names[i]+=i;
writeln(names);
}
```

which gives ["item1" "item2" "item3"]

regards